# Image upload is pointing to the right directory but not uploading

Tags: php, upload, permissions, wysiwyg, image-uploading

For this I'm using:

- redactor -> wysiwyg
- upload.php -> file that modifies image name and
  uploads

I'm using redactor to allow people to chat on my site. the imageUpload is pointing to a upload.php file correctly that contains the following code:

```
// files storage folder
$dir = '/image/upload/';

$_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
{
    // setting file's mysterious name
    $file = $dir.md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';
    // copying
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);

    // displaying file
    $array = array(
        'filelink' => $file
    );

    echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
}
```

The ajax is throwing a broken image in the wysiwyg that points to the right folder location and the modified file name correctly. The file itself is not actually getting uploaded

I've set the folder permissions to 775 with the following:

```
chmod -R 775 /foo/image
chmod -R 775 /foo/image/upload
```

I'm still having no luck on the image actually uploading. Is something wrong with my code? Maybe my permissions weren't set correctly?

UPDATE:

With the absolute path it wants to work but its telling me its a permissions problem now. Am I setting the wrong permissions or am I not setting the permissions to the right areas?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your server error logs?

Comment: Yes, its definitely a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your path is still incorrect, /image/ is trying to go to the root of your filesystem if im correct. Try adding the complete filesytem path before /image/ for example C:\websites\website\image\ etc..

Comment: I put the true path in and still nothing inside the upload folder

Comment: Okay this was partially the problem. The error log tells me its a permissions problem now with the absolute path set.

Comment: Awesome! Glad i could partially help :)